# the right way to listen to a own event after an intent received

Tags: android, service, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I want to create an app which wait for intent to be received (e.g. smsReceived).
When this happens I'll start listen with my custom event (e.g. some change in the prox sensor) and when this triggered i want to launch an activity.

So I'm struggling how make it happen (service,intentservice, broadcastreceiver, activity)
which will manage/launch what?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let a BroadcastReceiver receive the intent and launch a service from it, from the service you can start your activity.

Comment: Set a variable in shared preferences that indicates whether the broadcast receiver has been called, or better, when the broadcast is called, check if your service is up.

Comment: and the broadcastreceiver could continue recieving intents after the first one?
 I want to make sure its for one time only...